# How to sort a two-dimensional array in descending order for a column?

Tags: numpy

```
array([[ 0.  ,  0.04],
       [ 0.  ,  0.1 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.2 ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.4 ],
       [ 0.27,  1.  ],
       [ 0.3 ,  1.  ]])
```

How to sort the array by the second column in descend order in an simple way ?
The result's shape is also (6,2).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get `argsort` indices for the second column, flip them and index into rows -

```
a[a[:,1].argsort()[::-1]]
```

Alternatively, get `argsort` indices on negated version and index into rows -

```
a[(-a[:,1]).argsort()]
```

Comment: Thanks. How to sort the specified column.  Say, if the a's shape is (6,5) which has 5 columns. How to sort the fourth column.

Comment: @yanachen Use `a[:,3]` for the fourth column instead of `a[:,1]`.